# How to set a default tab with Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm using Jquery and Jquery UI with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabvanilla > ul').tabs({ fx: { height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' } });
});
```

Right now it automatically sets the first tabs as the default tab that is selected when the document loads. How do I override this and make the second tab the default selected tab when the page loads?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
$('#tabvanilla > ul').tabs({ selected: 1 });
```

More details on the [specifications page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected).

Answer (score 26):

If you happen to be using `jQuery UI >= 1.9`, this is how it works:

```
$(".selector" ).tabs({ active: 2 });
```

More details on the Tabs Widget API page: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

Comment: Note that this option is zero-based, so you need to supply `1` to select the second tab.

Answer (score 2):

I found this alternate solution which might be preferable in some situations:
http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/09/08/jquery-ui-tabs-changing-selected-tab/