# Stop jqueryUI Tab 0 from loading by default

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I can not find a solution to a simple problem: when all my `jqueryUI Tabs` are set to be `ajax` populated, then tab 0 is loaded by default every time I open the page... but I want the default tab to be tab 2. It can be accomplished with setting active property to tab id, but if I use `active : 2` in tabs init call, it first fires ajax request for tab 0, aborts it and then fires request for tab 2... I want to avoid that ajax request for tab 0. How can I do that in HTML+PHP environment?

Comment: How about canceling tab's first `beforeLoad` event?

Comment: and how would I do that? If I tell it to abort it still starts it but then aborts it - no joy.

Comment: A wild guess: `beforeLoad: function(event, ui) { if (first) { first = false; ui.jqXHR.abort(); } }`, with `var first = true;` somewhere at the beginning of the script. However, I'd expect jQuery to handle this when you set `active`, so this behavior may be a bug worth reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Try selected : 2

http://ui-dev.jquery.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected

and and older thread

[How to set a default tab with Jquery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377037/how-to-set-a-default-tab-with-jquery-ui)

```
$('#tabvanilla > ul').tabs({ selected: 1 });
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but well, no joy. `selected: 1` is for jQueryUi<1.9 and I am using 1.9+ so `active: 1` is a proper syntax. And it does work - the problem is it works only _after_ tab 0 is attempting to preload.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Add following line in your ajax file. (where you send your result to your main file)

```
$( "#your-selector" ).tabs({ active: 2 });
```