# How set active Tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I code 1 page php as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
?>
<div id="tabs" >
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class=""><a href="#tabs-1">Resize Image</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-2">Rotation Image</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#tabs-3">Crop Image</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"></div>
</div>
```

I had set tabs-2 active but it alway active tabs-1. Why? 
How set active other tab?

Comment: This is a Javascript question. Not  a PHP one...

Comment: The only PHP this question has are the opening and closing php tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377037/how-to-set-a-default-tab-with-jquery-ui

Comment: The active class is right, you have to create a css for this "active" class in order to make a difference between all tab, but it's only for design. You will have to use javascript to go directly on your tab2..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 $("#tabs").tabs({ selected: 2 });
```

or this:

```
 $("#tabs").tabs({ active: 2 });
```

Comment: Set $("#tabs").tabs({ active: 2 }); it's Ok . but i want sent param. the same $("#tabs").tabs({ active: $i }); Is it ok?

Comment: I don't now now your enviroment, but maybe works: $("#tabs").tabs({ active: <?php echo $i;?> })

Answer (score 3):

try something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HFFBA/)

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( {active:1});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to have fully functional non javascript implementation. You can use something like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="<?= $params['action'] == 'link1' ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="#tabs-1">link1</a></li>
  <li class="<?= $params['action'] == 'link2' ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="#tabs-2">link2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I set: <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-2">Rotation Image</a></li>